# Upstairs/downstairs neighbors

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I just moved from the suburbs to my first apartment building a little less than six months ago, and I was wondering how I could could concisely refer to all the other residents of the building. I can, of course, use the phrases "upstairs neighbors" and "downstairs neighbors", but I live in the middle of the building, and I would feel awkward saying "upstairs and downstairs neighbors" or "same-building neighbors". Is there a word for this?

EDIT: I would just say "neighbors", but I would like to make it clear that I mean just the people in my building, not other people in my region of Manhattan, or people in adjacent buildings.

Comment: *Neighbors* by itself wouldn't suffice?

Comment: [You want to know what to call the people who live in the same building as you do without calling them the people who live in the same building as you do?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment15959_4732)

Comment: "people"........

Comment: Interesting nugget I found while Googling this question: In Hindi, the word for *upstairs neighbor* means *God* (or *god*, I'm unsure of the capitalization here).

Comment: Most people I know who live in apartment buildings just refer to the other people in the same building as "neighbors". The larger the building, the more likely "neighbors" will refer *exclusively* to same-building residents.

Comment: I have just coined a new word - 'domiciliants'. You should speak of your 'fellow domiciliants of Exquisite Apartments'.

Comment: I'd love to, WS2, but I fear I may be perceived as a madman. I'll give it my consideration, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to them as, "My fellow (building)  **_____** ."

- occupants
- renters
- residents

I like residents the best.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply call them all your [*cotenants*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cotenants).

Comment: I would have thought cotenant would mean a flat-mate; where all flat-mates have signed the lease.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Merriam-Webster defines [tenant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenant) as "a person, business, group, etc., that pays to use another person's property." When you say, "the building has 18 tenants," that doesn't imply that they are all in one unit.

Comment: I agree that "18 tenants" should be interpreted as 18 units with 18 separate leases, but does _co_-tenant have the same meaning? To my tin ear, a co-tenant sounds like someone who is sharing the lease with me, not someone who is renting a different unit in the same building.

Comment: @DilipSarwate To use a different example, a commercial building with 6 units occupied has 6 tenants -- all of whom are cotenants of that building.

Comment: Ugly term, but could work in an apartment building where everybody *rents* their apartment. Not every apartment-dweller does.

Comment: @ErikKowal A tenant "pays to use another person's property." Which doesn't restrict itself to _rent_.

Comment: @Gnawme - What's the relevance of that to my comment?

Comment: @ErikKowal You italicized _rent_ as if that's the only way to become a tenant.

Comment: @Gnawme - Please clarify the other ways. Isn't renting the usual, most common way of becoming a tenant?

Answer (score 1):

Try *fellow-residents.*​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Except that doesn't make the distinction the poster asks for. You could say "the fellow residents of my neighborhood" or "the fellow residents of my town" just as well as "the fellow resident of my building". Without additional words to specify, no one would know which you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest  [**co-dwellers**](http://www.fluxre.com/blog/multi-unit-buildings-2/).

> [**dweller**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dweller): a person who inhabits a particular place.

Comment: I like the sound of this, but I fear it might be seen as somewhat cryptic?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear to me. Do you mean, how can I refer to other people in my apartment building as opposed to other people in the same area of the city? For of course, if you say "my neighbors", most people would take that to include people in other nearby buildings.

If that's what you mean, I don't think there's one word for this concept in English. People usually say, "the people in my building".

Comment: Yes, as opposed to the other people in my area of Manhattan. I will clarify this in an edit of my question. Thank you.